# Performing a GET request with custom headers using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api, request-headers

I want to hit my API endpoint using jQuery's ajax function.

Here's the endpoint I need to hit:

```
curl -X GET \
     -H "X-Algolia-API-Key: ${API_KEY}" \
     -H "X-Algolia-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
     "https://analytics.algolia.com/1/searches/${index}/popular?startAt=${startAt}&endAt=${endAt}"
```

Here's what I've tried using javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  url: algoliaApiEndpoint,
  type: "GET",
  crossDomain: true,
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Algolia-API-Key", _ALGOLIA_API_KEY);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Algolia-Application-Id", _ALGOLIA_ID);
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
});
```

I'm seeing this error:

> {"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"OPTIONS is not allowed"}

---

How can I replicate that `curl` command into javascript with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

- Open Chrome DevTool
- Select Network tab
- Update page
- Filter XHR requests
- Find that request
- Mouse right click and click in context menu `Copy->Copy as cURL`
- Compare with your cURL request

I think you have problem with CORS and node-restify. I have the same problem.

[image]